What regex function could I use to find the answers?
Here is the types of string I have in Python:
$\textbf{(A) }4\qquad\textbf{(B) }6\qquad\textbf{(C) }7\qquad\textbf{(D) }10\qquad\textbf{(E) }11$
$\textbf{(A)}\ 2S + 3\qquad \textbf{(B)}\ 3S + 2\qquad \textbf{(C)}\ 3S + 6 \qquad\textbf{(D)}\ 2S + 6 \qquad \textbf{(E)}\ 2S + 12$
$\textbf{(A) }50 \qquad \textbf{(B) }52  \qquad \textbf{(C) }54 \qquad \textbf{(D) }56 \qquad \textbf{(E) }58$
$\text{(A) }4^4 5^5 6^6 \qquad \text{(B) }4^4 5^6 6^5 \qquad \text{(C) }4^5 5^4 6^6 \qquad \text{(D) }4^6 5^4 6^5 \qquad \text{(E) }4^6 5^5 6^4$
$\mathrm{(A) \ } \frac{1}{4}\qquad \mathrm{(B) \ } \frac13\qquad \mathrm{(C) \ } \frac38\qquad \mathrm{(D) \ } \frac25\qquad \mathrm{(E) \ } \frac12$

I want to extract the answers from these lines, i.e. the text after the (A), (B), (C), (D) and (E). For example, for the first line, I would like to get:
[4, 6, 7, 10, 11]

For the last line:
[\frac{1}{4}, \frac13, \frac38, \frac25, \frac12]

There is a lot of variation in the lines and I can't find a regex that can do the job. Any help would be appreciated.
I tried to use something like:
line = "$\textbf{(A) }4\qquad\textbf{(B) }6\qquad\textbf{(C) }7\qquad\textbf{(D) }10\qquad\textbf{(E) }11$"
A = re.findall(r"(?<=A)(.*)(?=B)", line)

and I get:
[') }4\\textbf{(']

to find what was between A and B and do something similar for the other answers but there was always "junk" that I could'nt get rid off.

[int(x) for x in re.findall(r"(\d+)\\qquad", line)] gives output [4, 6, 7, 10], do you want something like this?

It works for the first line but sometimes I have \frac{1}{2} or other kinds of math and it doesn't work.

Python module for parsing LaTex

May be you need something like the following (non-greedy regex matching with .*?, a lazy version of .*), for example to extract the string in between { and \qquad use the following:
for s in \
    [r'$\textbf{(A) }4\qquad\textbf{(B) }6\qquad\textbf{(C) }7\qquad\textbf{(D) }10\qquad\textbf{(E) }11$',
     r'$\textbf{(A)}\ 2S + 3\qquad \textbf{(B)}\ 3S + 2\qquad \textbf{(C)}\ 3S + 6 \qquad\textbf{(D)}\ 2S + 6 \qquad \textbf{(E)}\ 2S + 12$',
     r'$\textbf{(A) }50 \qquad \textbf{(B) }52  \qquad \textbf{(C) }54 \qquad \textbf{(D) }56 \qquad \textbf{(E) }58$',
     r'$\text{(A) }4^4 5^5 6^6 \qquad \text{(B) }4^4 5^6 6^5 \qquad \text{(C) }4^5 5^4 6^6 \qquad \text{(D) }4^6 5^4 6^5 \qquad \text{(E) }4^6 5^5 6^4$',
     r'$\mathrm{(A) \ } \frac{1}{4}\qquad \mathrm{(B) \ } \frac13\qquad \mathrm{(C) \ } \frac38\qquad \mathrm{(D) \ } \frac25\qquad \mathrm{(E) \ } \frac12$']:
    
     print([x.strip() for x in re.findall(r"\}(.*?)\\qquad", s])

# ['4', '6', '7', '10']
# ['\\ 2S + 3', '\\ 3S + 2', '\\ 3S + 6', '\\ 2S + 6']
# ['50', '52', '54', '56']
# ['4^4 5^5 6^6', '4^4 5^6 6^5', '4^5 5^4 6^6', '4^6 5^4 6^5']
# ['\\frac{1}{4}', '\\frac13', '\\frac38', '\\frac25']


You could match the capital letter (A-F maybe?), and then the closing brace, the content up to the next \\qquad or $. The pairs of letter/content can be passed to the dict constructor:
import re

data = [
    r"$\textbf{(A) }4\qquad\textbf{(B) }6\qquad\textbf{(C) }7\qquad\textbf{(D) }10\qquad\textbf{(E) }11$",
    r"$\textbf{(A)}\ 2S + 3\qquad \textbf{(B)}\ 3S + 2\qquad \textbf{(C)}\ 3S + 6 \qquad\textbf{(D)}\ 2S + 6 \qquad \textbf{(E)}\ 2S + 12$",
    r"$\textbf{(A) }50 \qquad \textbf{(B) }52  \qquad \textbf{(C) }54 \qquad \textbf{(D) }56 \qquad \textbf{(E) }58$",
    r"$\text{(A) }4^4 5^5 6^6 \qquad \text{(B) }4^4 5^6 6^5 \qquad \text{(C) }4^5 5^4 6^6 \qquad \text{(D) }4^6 5^4 6^5 \qquad \text{(E) }4^6 5^5 6^4$",
    r"$\mathrm{(A) \ } \frac{1}{4}\qquad \mathrm{(B) \ } \frac13\qquad \mathrm{(C) \ } \frac38\qquad \mathrm{(D) \ } \frac25\qquad \mathrm{(E) \ } \frac12$"
]

for line in data:
    parts = dict(re.findall(r"([A-F])\W*?}(.*?)(?:\\qquad|$)", line))
    print(parts)

This outputs:
{'A': '4', 'B': '6', 'C': '7', 'D': '10', 'E': '11$'}
{'A': '\\ 2S + 3', 'B': '\\ 3S + 2', 'C': '\\ 3S + 6 ', 'D': '\\ 2S + 6 ', 'E': '\\ 2S + 12$'}
{'A': '50 ', 'B': '52  ', 'C': '54 ', 'D': '56 ', 'E': '58$'}
{'A': '4^4 5^5 6^6 ', 'B': '4^4 5^6 6^5 ', 'C': '4^5 5^4 6^6 ', 'D': '4^6 5^4 6^5 ', 'E': '4^6 5^5 6^4$'}
{'A': ' \\frac{1}{4}', 'B': ' \\frac13', 'C': ' \\frac38', 'D': ' \\frac25', 'E': ' \\frac12$'}


If you want to get only the numbers from the text, you can easily use:
"(\d+)"

When try it on regex101 platform, the results are:

also, you can use Regex:
"\}?\{?(\d+)\\?\}?"

to skip all special & un-wanted characters, and the results should be as this:


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
